# Draggable doesn't work when created with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, draggable

I got a little issue with my draggable div, when I create a div with function, I can't move it in my Web browser, whereas when I declare it in HTML, that works perfectly.

HTML:

```
<div id="pion" class="draggable" draggable="true">1</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function randomIntFromInterval(min,max) // random number between 2 args
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}

function ajouteElement() //function add an element
{
    var e = document.createElement("div");
    var val= randomIntFromInterval(0,15);
    e.appendChild( document.createTextNode(val) );
    e.id = "pion";
    e.className="draggable";
    e.draggable="true";
    hand.appendChild(e);
}
```

Comment: And the problem is... ?

Comment: `e.draggable=true;`, not `e.draggable="true";`.

Comment: _or_ `e.setAttribute('draggable', 'true');` - the distinction being that a string is okay here.

Comment: in the first case I can move the div and in the second I can't, I change    e.draggable="true"; to    e.draggable=true; that doesn't change anythings

Comment: what is hand?  Does hand exist when this javascript executes?

Comment: Works fine for me (if you define `hand`): https://jsfiddle.net/tys7uqa6/1/

Comment: Hand is the div declared in my HTML, I see the element but i can't move it

Comment: Ok this juste does't work on Firefox web browser, on chrome that's fine but the piece who is moved is not this one who get dropped

Comment: @Mountainfox - from the code shown, `hand` won't be draggable. The element that will is the one you've created in the JS - the one with the id of `pion`. Naturally, you'll need handlers for `ondragstart` of the src element and `ondrop` + `ondragover` for the tgt element.

Comment: Ok I just add the class dragable on the div and that work fine!! Thank you lot of  :D